# Draw lines in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to draw a line in Qt( Qt 5.9.0- MinGW 32 bit) ,but just page is blue. this program  run with older QT. I tried to change my program, but it did not work.

when I added Qt += opengl to pro file Qt show error and finally added library to pro file.

```
QT       += core gui
QT += opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DrawLine
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
LIBS += -lopengl32
```

Class widget for function opengl.

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QGLWidget>  //QT  +=  opengl
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>  //QT  +=  gui


class GLWidget : public QGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0, QGLWidget *shareWidget = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL()override;
    void paintGL()override;
    void resizeGL(int width, int height)override;

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private:
    int sample;
};
```

I wrote this code, but only the blue screen did not show up.

```
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent, QGLWidget *shareWidget)
    : QGLWidget(parent, shareWidget)
{
    sample = 0;
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
//    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 102.0/255.0, 0.0);
//          glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
//          glLoadIdentity();
//          glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{

   glClearColor(0.1,0.6,0.7,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    switch (sample)
    {
    case 0:
        glColor3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
        glBegin(GL_LINE);
        glVertex2f(-50, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);
        glEnd();
        break;
        //--------------------------------
    case 1:
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(-50, 0);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);
        glEnd();
        break;
        //--------------------------------
    case 2:
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(-50, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);

        glVertex2f(0, -50);
        glVertex2f(0, 50);
        glEnd();
        break;
        //--------------------------------
    case 3:
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 50);
        glVertex2f(-50, 50);
        glEnd();
        break;
        //--------------------------------
    case 4:
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 50);
        glVertex2f(-50, 50);
        glEnd();
        break;
        //--------------------------------
    case 5:
        glLineWidth(5);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 0);
        glVertex2f(50, 50);
        glVertex2f(-50, 50);
        glEnd();
        glLineWidth(1);
        break;
    }
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);//set viewport, don't rely on default values

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, -1, 1);
}


void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    switch(e->key())
    {
    case 'A':
        sample  = sample < 5 ? sample + 1 : sample;
        break;
    case 'S':
        sample  = sample > 0 ? sample - 1 : sample;
    };

    ((QMainWindow*)this->parent())->setWindowTitle(QString::number(sample));

    updateGL();
}
```

here I create a new layout to show my widget in page.

```
  #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    glW = new GLWidget(0, 0);
    QGridLayout *layout1 = new QGridLayout();
    QWidget *centralWidget1 = new QWidget(this);
    centralWidget1->setLayout(layout1);

    layout1->addWidget(glW);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget1);
    //this->layout()->addWidget(glW);

  //  glW->setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480);
  //  glW->setFocus();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete glW;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is caused because `QGLWidget` does not handle the focus, so when you press a key you never call `keyPressEvent`, the solution is to set the focus policy with [`setFocusPolicy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop):

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent, QGLWidget *shareWidget)
    : QGLWidget(parent, shareWidget)
{
    sample = 0;
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
}
```

**Note:**

`GL_LINE` only serves as a parameter to use [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml), so that instruction does not draw any lines.

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49196328) you can find the complete example.

Comment: Thanks, But I run the program, just a blue screen will be displayed. Can be a problem with me opengl?

Comment: @Saeed.Nowroozi Have you pressed the keys? when you press the keys the lines will appear. To do this, first click with the mouse on the window, and then the keys.

Comment: yes, but does not show any line. I try test other program but does not draw any thing.

Comment: @Saeed.Nowroozi Try changing ``50`` to ``0.5``.